# Select every n values in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I would like to choose from a column every 3 values.

For example:

```
  Input
   12 
   73
   56 
   33
   16


                  output
                    12
                    73
                    56 
                    ------
                    73
                    56
                    33
                    -----
                    56
                    33
                    16
```

I have tried to add a key column and group by it, but my data frame is too large to perform the grouping. Here is my attempt:

```
df.groupby('key').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. Won't you have 3 times as many rows in the new column as the others?

Comment: do you need the output to relate to other data in the table? With lists this would be very easy.

Comment: Not exactly 3 times more but the number of window slides times window size (=3).  that's what i would like to have.

Comment: It doesn't have to relate to the other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use list type, you can do like this :

```
lst = [12,73,56,33,16]
slide_size=3
result = []

for i in range(0,len(lst)-slide_size+1):
    result.append(lst[i:i+3])

result

# output : [[12, 73, 56], [73, 56, 33], [56, 33, 16]]
```

After this, you can transform the list to DataFrame